# Why aren't menus integrated in bar when running as super user?

Tags: unity, root, gui, menu

When I open any window as root, menus aren't integrated in the menu bar or in the window's title bar. Why does this happen? Can I prevent this behavior?

[image: Nautilus as super-user]

Comment: It doesn't matter whether I type 'sudo su' and 'nautilus' or 'gnome-terminal'; 'sudo nautilus' or 'gksu nautilus'. It always open with the menu non-integrated. Furthermore, theme has no effect on this behavior